# Apple's AdvancedTableViewCells Question

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm looking at Apple's "AdvancedTableViewCells" sample project, and in looking at the `RootViewController`, I noticed the nib loading for the `IndividualSubviewsBasedApplicationCell`. I was wondering about that nib loading... what is it loading into? There is no handle/variable. I understand the lines below where cell is assigned to the view via the `IBOutlet`, but I don't understand the line: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IndividualSubviewsBasedApplicationCell" owner:self options:nil];`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ApplicationCell";

    ApplicationCell *cell = (ApplicationCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

#if USE_INDIVIDUAL_SUBVIEWS_CELL
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IndividualSubviewsBasedApplicationCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = tmpCell;
        self.tmpCell = nil;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Jeff LaMarche's article [Table View Cells in Interface Builder - the Apple Way™](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/09/table-view-cells-in-interface-builder.html).

In the NIB file `IndividualSubviewsBasedApplicationCell`, "File's Owner" is set to `RootViewController`, and the custom `UITableViewCell` is connected to the `tmpCell` `IBOutlet` of `RootViewController`.

In the line:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IndividualSubviewsBasedApplicationCell" owner:self options:nil];
```

...the bundle loader loads the NIB file and connects all the outlets. Once it has done this, the `tmpCell` `IBOutlet` now points to our custom `UITableViewCell`.